# turn off display without shifting window position

Tags: windows-10, external-display, desktop-customization

I am doing some presenting and would like to turn off the screen of my laptop after starting various media on an external display (HDMI). I would like to accomplish this in real-time without the currently open windows on the primary display shifting to the external display. Essentially, I would like to make the primary display go dark without disabling it. Does Windows 10 have this functionality built in?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You could set the brightness of the screen in one of the following ways: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/44213-adjust-screen-brightness-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Depends on your laptop model. There is usually a keyboard shortcut to turn off the display or just the backlight. I know Dell for example has an "Unobtrusive mode" shortcut (fn+F7) to turn off all lights, but must first be enabled in the bios.